# java.net.ConnectException after switching accesspoint using WifiNetworkSpecifier on Android 10

Tags: android, okhttp, wifimanager, android-10.0, self-signed-certificate

Unable to make connection after configuring wifi accespoint using WifiNetworkSpecifier, Below is the trace

`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.123.45.1 (port 443) from /:: (port 0) after 120000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:58)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:268)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:174)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
    ... 29 more`

While using the wifiManager to connect my IOT device. I started receiving a connection error for App sdk targeting to Android 10. Initially, I started connect to SSID using WifiNetworkSpecifier as below,

```
val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssid)
            .build()
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
            .build()

    connManager.requestNetwork(request, object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
         startLocalConnection(network)
    }

    override fun onUnavailable() {
        // do failure processing here..
    }

})
```

after connection to the SSID in onAvailable() callback makes an okhttp connection to my local IOT device http server using self-signed certificate as below,

```
fun startLocalConnection(){
    val trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS")
    val rawResource = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.device)
    trusted.load(rawResource, "password")
    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    trustManagerFactory.init(trusted)
    val trustManager: X509TrustManager = trustManagerFactory.trustManagers
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null)
    val socketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
    val trustManager: X509TrustManager = trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager

    var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(listOf(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS))
            .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://192.168.40.23/device/json")
            .build()

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            // Success
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            // Causing java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.40.23
        }
   }}
```

Please help me to trace and fix the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare, log trace is java.net.ConnectException when using okhttpclient in android10 for new API changes

Comment: That is not a [a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/115145). You can [use Logcat to examine the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) and copy it to paste into your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, updated log trace and edited my question, please help me to solve this

Comment: In your Request.builder(), you do not specify any port in the url?

Comment: @Santhosh I also have difficulty using networkspecifier. After accepting the connection what is happening: the wifi remains connected to the access point? what happens if you do nothing in the onavailable () callback?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem now.

In your onAvailable callback, you have to bind your network with your device with:

```
((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .bindProcessToNetwork(network);
```